# debug nasty horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, debugging

I think i got myself entangled in a CSS maze. I notice a horizontal scroll on my site in desktop browsers (firefox and chromium), when in responsive mode. Tested in android, and it seems ok.

The website is [cv.pixyz.net](http:///www.cv.pixyz.net)

To debug it, I tried all of the following:

- Looking for elements getting bigger than the parent's space.
- I thought the container with #id was the problem, because web developer toolbar shows that closer to the edges of the screen, but removing that, didn't solve this
- Used this to see if anything gets out of bounds. some elements stand out, but still can't solve the scroll
- I tried these 2 snippets:

```js
// snippet 1
var docWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;

[].forEach.call(
  document.querySelector('body *'),
  function(el) {
    console.log(el);
    // console.log(el.offsetWidth);
    // console.log(docWidth);
    if (el.offsetWidth > docWidth) {
      console.log(el);
    }
  }
);

// snippet 2
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*"), i = 0, rect;
for (; i < all.length; i++) {
    rect = all[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.right < 0) all[i].style.outline = "1px solid green";
}
```

but there's no effect either: no logs registered, no border changed

- started removing other elements in the page. Even doing this, I still get scroll:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- domActual = <?php echo $ambiente; ?> -->
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>Sobre mim... @ Luis Aguiar</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="container">
    <h2 class="nome">Sobre mim... / Luis Aguiar</h2>
    <a class="dominio" href="http://www.cv.pixyz.net">cv.pixyz.net</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#id">ID</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#dev">Dev</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <footer>
    <p>Todos os direitos reservados @ Luis Aguiar</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

- I also tried this to check abnormal widths: (http://wernull.com/2013/04/debug-ghost-css-elements-causing-unwanted-scrolling/):

```css
* {
    outline: 1px solid blue!important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Does anyone know what is causing this, or have any other idea for debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be the following line :

```
<section id="dev">
    [...]
    <li class="job"> /* 2nd li element */
        [...]
        <p class="url">https://www.demarca.eu/</p> /* <- This line */
```

The URL has no breaking spaces, so once the window reaches the width of the URL string it can't wrap the string and therefore the scrollbar gets added.

The options you have are:

1. Shorten the text: 
   Consider whether you need to display the full URL including `https://` - maybe instead include it as a link? e.g.:
   `<p class="url"><a href="https://www.demarca.eu/">www.demarca.eu</a></p>`
2. Use lowercase: the CSS changes the text to uppercase, which adds to the width of the string.
3. Wrap the URL: forcing the string to wrap is often the best option, but it doesn't suit a url so well because urls can't have spaces. However if you do want to make it wrap, you can create the following CSS class and add it to the element:
   `.wrap { word-wrap: break-word; }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what it was, but after reboot, was ok (... but i cleaned the cache!). The situation persisted even without css and barebones HTML. After this, i did what you said, just in case (and because it looks nicer!). Thanks for the support!